# Consul agent are still marked as in critical state after terminating whole instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, consul

I'm running consul inside docker and using `gliderlabs/consul-agent` 
Here how i launch agents:

```
(export IP44=$(wget -qO- 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4);consul agent -config-dir=/config -data-dir /opt/consul -advertise $IP44 -atlas=${ATLAS_REPO} -atlas-join  -atlas-token=${ATLAS_TOKEN})
```

in `/config` there is an `agent.json` file with following content (default from that docker image):

```
{
        "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
        "data_dir": "/data",
        "leave_on_terminate": true,
        "dns_config": {
                "allow_stale": true,
                "max_stale": "1s"
        }
}
```

The problem is that when I terminate my instance I'm still seeing it in atlas console and its marked as

> Agent not live or unreachable

If I terminate a lot of instance there will be a lot of nodes in atlas that show up as not live and failed checks, and the whole infracture are marked as having critical problems because of it.
Isn't `leave_on_terminate` should be solving the problem? How to solve this issue?

UPD

Here what i see in logs:

```
2016-03-02 01:15:51 UTC+3
2016/03/01 22:15:51 [INFO] Graceful shutdown over 0
2016-03-02 01:15:51 UTC+3
2016-03-02 01:15:51 UTC+3
2016/03/01 22:15:51 [INFO] Down
2016-03-02 01:15:51 UTC+3
2016-03-02 01:15:51 UTC+3
2016/03/01 22:15:51 [INFO] consul: Deregistering fabio
2016-03-02 01:15:51 UTC+3
2016-03-02 01:15:51 UTC+3
2016/03/01 22:15:51 [INFO] consul: Health changed to #141


2016-03-02 01:16:03 UTC+3
2016/03/01 22:16:03 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect 577111e23c93 has failed, no acks received
2016-03-02 01:16:08 UTC+3
2016-03-02 01:16:06 UTC+3
2016/03/01 22:16:06 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect 577111e23c93 has failed, no acks received
2016-03-02 01:16:08 UTC+3
2016-03-02 01:16:08 UTC+3
2016/03/01 22:16:08 [INFO] memberlist: Marking 577111e23c93 as failed, suspect timeout reached
2016-03-02 01:16:13 UTC+3
2016-03-02 01:16:08 UTC+3
2016/03/01 22:16:08 [INFO] serf: EventMemberFailed: 577111e23c93 10.0.1.61
2016-03-02 01:16:13 UTC+3
2016-03-02 01:16:24 UTC+3
2016/03/01 22:16:24 [INFO] serf: attempting reconnect to 577111e23c93 10.0.1.61:8301
```

`UPD` This is happening on `Amazon EC2 ecs optimized amis`, don't know about other but i guess it would be same.

Comment: First of all, I recommend you to update your consul agents to the latest version. As for the question, 1) try to search your answer here: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues?q=leave_on_terminate and 2) read the last paragraph in consul docs https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/basics.html about node reaping process - it is not immediate for failed nodes.

Comment: I have the latest docker consul image.1) didnt find any usefull there 2) Yes, but reaping are taking way too long, for this 72h whole cluster are marked as critical unhealthy, which is not good.

Comment: Did you wait until the end of the reaping process, e.g. 72h? Did nodes get removed from cluster successfully?